# How we can upload file from our system in website?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

Could you please let me know how I can upload one pdf from my system into the website. Here is the example of my code, but its not working :

```
Driver.get("https://www.pdfunlock.com/");
Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
Driver.findElement(By.id("fromComputer")).click();
Driver.findElement(By.id("Open")).click();
WebElement = Driver.find_element_by_id("fileUpload")
element.send_keys("C:\myfile.txt")
```

Please help.

Thankiew.

Comment: "Not working" expresses nothing. Things that doesn't work always come with an error or explanation.

Comment: `findElement` is for java. But `find_element_by_id` is for python. Which language are you using?

Comment: I want to upload a code in java. Above code i tried from internet. Please help for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium WebDriver operates only on browser DOM window. When you are trying to upload a file, you are intending to automate a windows level flow, which is out-of-scope for selenium. In short, you cannot use selenium in any form to upload a file.

But... you can do so, using Java's **Robot** API, or using an **AutoIT script**.

Please visit this link to learn more about AutoIt, and file uploading using it.
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

To use the compiled AuoIT script in your Java code, simply use this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathToTheExecutableFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Robot API to interact with Windows pop-up or Browse windows . Selenium will not be able to interact with Windows file browser.

Go through this for quick overview:

[Reference Link](http://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html)

I am assuming you are not able to upload because you need to browse to your local location to upload to your website

Answer (score 0):

try this (Only Drawback of this is you have to be on the opened browser open dialog when this code is running i.e. this code won't run in background) :

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Lists {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.pdfunlock.com/");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='fromComputer']")).click();

        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\kushal\\Desktop\\1.pdf";
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(filePath);
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection);

        Robot robot = new Robot();



        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 


    }

}
```

Comment: Please check your imports.

Comment: @ajaykumar share your complete code including your imports in your question body

Comment: public class SSI {
public static void main(String[] args) { System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");  
  WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
 Driver.get("https://www.pdfunlock.com/");
Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);  
Driver.findElement(By.id("fromComputer")).click();  Driver.findElement(By.id(".sendKeys("C:\\Users\\ajay.kumar\\Desktop\\head-first-java-2nd-edition.pdf");))

Comment: The code which I shared works well, just make sure you are present on the launched browser screen, if error persists then please share complete errorstacktrace

Comment: VK_CONTROL cannot be resolved or is not a field...it shows this error for keyevent. Please check

Comment: @ajaykumar I've updated my answer, please run the same exact code, and let me know if it works?

Comment: Yes, Kunal. I tried but it shows me error message ' VK_CONTROL CANNOT BE RESOLVED OR IS NOT A FIELD"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139321/discussion-between-ajay-kumar-and-kushal).

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code (Robot API)  to upload a file to website, if you are using java.

```
//After Open Upload window 
//Copy the file path in clipboard

    StringSelection ss=new StringSelection("File path");
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);

//Paste your copied path in modal window using mouse events

            Robot rb=new Robot();
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Its not working, I've try this it is giving error for new string.

Comment: Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  
  Driver.findElement(By.id("fromComputer")).click();
  Driver.findElement(By.id(".sendKeys("C:\\Users\\ajay.kumar\\Desktop\\head-first-java-2nd-edition.pdf");))
*/  
  /*Driver.findElement(By.id("Open")).click();
  WebElement = Driver.find_element_by_id("fileUpload")
    element.send_keys("C:\myfile.txt")*/